# Parse JSON from GoogleApiBooks

Tags: json, swift, xcode, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to parse this JSON but it don't works.

This is the JSON:

```
{
  "kind": "books#volumes",
  "totalItems": 1,
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "books#volume",
      "id": "uCHmPQAACAAJ",
      "etag": "aBZ3KnoRsq4",
      "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/uCHmPQAACAAJ",
      "volumeInfo": {
        "title": "Psicologia delle folle",
        "authors": [
          "Gustave Le Bon"
        ],
        "publishedDate": "2004",
        "industryIdentifiers": [
          {
            "type": "ISBN_10",
            "identifier": "8850206240"
          },
          {
            "type": "ISBN_13",
            "identifier": "9788850206247"
          }
        ],
        "readingModes": {
          "text": false,
          "image": false
        },
        "pageCount": 251,
        "printType": "BOOK",
        "categories": [
          "Psychology"
        ],
        "maturityRating": "NOT_MATURE",
        "allowAnonLogging": false,
        "contentVersion": "preview-1.0.0",
        "language": "it",
      },
      "saleInfo": {
        "country": "IT",
        "saleability": "NOT_FOR_SALE",
        "isEbook": false
      },
      "accessInfo": {
        "country": "IT",
        "viewability": "NO_PAGES",
        "embeddable": false,
        "publicDomain": false,
        "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
        "epub": {
          "isAvailable": false
        },
        "pdf": {
          "isAvailable": false
        },
        ,
        "accessViewStatus": "NONE",
        "quoteSharingAllowed": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is the code that i'm using:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn9788850206247&key=my-key"


    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["items"].arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                print(self.arrRes)
            }
            if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                self.tableProva.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableProva.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellProva", for: indexPath) as! CellProvaClass
    var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel?.text = dict["title"] as? String
    cell.authorLabel?.text = dict["authors"] as? String
    return cell
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your JSON Reponse ( in short format) :

[image]

And this is the data structure (Array and dictionary format) :
[image]

Now you have to access : `title` and `authors` so here is your value in cellforRowAtIndexPath Method , a dictionary having name **`dict`** stores values of `volumeInfo ( a Dictionary)` :

so you have to use this way to access title :

```
cell.titleLabel?.text = dict["volumeInfo"]["title"] as? String

//To Fetch Author array
  if let authorArray = dict["volumeInfo"]["authors"] as? NSArray{
          print(authorArray)
   }
```

and then to access author is an array so which index of value you want to show in  `cell.authorLabel` .

In Second Screenshot those which are enclosed with `{} is Dictionary and [] is Array`

First try to show Title and then same way try to fetch value of author array and set according to your requirement.

Feel Free to comment if any further issue.

Comment: How can I take the "authors"?

Answer (score 0):

When you are parsing the JSON on line

`if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["items"].arrayObject {`

you will receive an object of NSDictionary which contains all other nested elements & arrays in keys. In your tableView delegate you are directly accessing the value from arrRes by unboxing it to NSDictionary object. All the entries are available in an array named `items` which further has a nested object `volumeInfo` which contains the info about title & another array of `Authors`.

You need to extract the further nested objects from `arrRes` object to use it in your `tableView cellForRowAtIndex` delegate function.

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: I understand what the problem is. How do I get "title" and "author" from "volumeInfo"? I am still inexperienced regarding the use of json